# How to connect my lamp server from another computer

Tags: networking, server

I am entirely new to ubuntu.Few days ago I have installed ubuntu 15.10 desktop edition.I have installed LAMP server,SSH.I have also created virtual host and checked whether i can access my web page in my ubuntu.Everything works well.I want to see my webpage from another computer which is somewhere far to my server.How can I do that? Please Help me.

Comment: Check http://canyouseeme.org/ port 80 and 443 (HTTPS) of your domain to see if port forwarding is set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit apache2.conf and put entry:

```
 Listen 0.0.0.0:8080 or Listen 192.168.0.0:8080

 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

*sudo netstat -napW | grep apache* 
It will show Apache listening on port 80 for your external interface or not.

```
services apache2 restart
```